# rcharts dimple bubble chart in shiny

Tags: r, rcharts, shiny-server, dimple.js

Using a variation of the below example dimple chart, how can I get this to auto scale with Shiny bootstrap without having to hard code height and width of the chart?

```
#get data used by dimple for all of its examples as a first test
data <- read.delim(
  "http://pmsi-alignalytics.github.io/dimple/data/example_data.tsv"
)

#eliminate . to avoid confusion in javascript
colnames(data) <- gsub("[.]","",colnames(data))


#example 27 Bubble Matrix
d1 <- dPlot(
  x = c( "Channel", "PriceTier"),
  y = "Owner",
  z = "Distribution",
  groups = "PriceTier",
  data = data,
  type = "bubble",
  aggregate = "dimple.aggregateMethod.max"
)
d1$xAxis( type = "addCategoryAxis" )
d1$yAxis( type = "addCategoryAxis" )
d1$zAxis( type = "addMeasureAxis", overrideMax = 200 )
d1$legend(
  x = 200,
  y = 10,
  width = 500,
  height = 20,
  horizontalAlign = "right"
)
d1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you have to put `width="100%"` in `dplot()`, like this :

```
d1 <- dPlot(
  x = c( "Channel", "PriceTier"),
  y = "Owner",
  z = "Distribution",
  groups = "PriceTier",
  data = data,
  type = "bubble",
  aggregate = "dimple.aggregateMethod.max",
  width="100%"
)
```

Comment: thanks so much for answering this;  I am trying to incorporate all the new dimple functionality here https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts/tree/dimple_layer if you want to be on the cutting edge.  Here is one example http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/8869959.  I would love thoughts or ideas.

Comment: Great work! It's very interesting, the graph are amazing. I'll let you know if i have some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Victorp I managed to just get deeper with JQuery and Bootstrap. The biggest pain is the fixed dimensions but the scaffolding with bootstrap is proving very useful.

Comment: @timelyportfolio I want to thank you for the excellent libraries. Really loving Dimple as my preferred visualization library. I will definitely go through the links you have provided. Also, finalising my shiny dashboard with multiple dimple plots - will shoot it over if you like.